# Couldn't find constant error - PHP

Tags: php

Hi can some one please point out my mistake here. I've got two PHP files. First view.php goes as follows; and the second as processor.php
I see the if(constant('SELECTitem') == $i) line doesnt capture the desired input to be compared with $i hence straight goes to 'else' validation. Please correct me. Thanks.

### view.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL="SELECT sbstart, sbend FROM newchk";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor=mysql_num_rows($run);

define("SELECTitem", form.options.value);
?>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateData(form) 
{
var TextIn = document.getElementById('txtN');
if(form.txtN.value == "")
{
alert("Text field is empty"); 
return false;
}else{
alert ((form.options[form.options.selectedIndex].value) + (form.txtN.value));
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return ValidateData(this)" method="POST" action="processor.php">
<select STYLE='width:90px' name="options"><?php
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
    for($i=$rec['sbstart']; $i<=$rec['sbend']; $i++)
    {
    echo "<option id='options' value='$i'>$i<br></option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtN">
<input type="submit" name="subN" value="Save">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### processor.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL="SELECT * FROM newchk";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor=mysql_num_rows($run);

while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
for($i=$rec['sbstart']; $i<=$rec['sbend']; $i++)
    {
    if(constant('SELECTitem') == $i)
     {
        if($rec['totsb'] <= "0")
        {
        echo "You have already entred this cheque number."; 
        return false;
        } else {
        echo "You can proceed withi this entry"; 
        return false;
        }
     }
     else 
     { echo "Error: Cant find choosen in the databse"; 
      return false;
     }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit to processor.php, the constant you created in the previous page will not be carried over. Also, when you are defining the constant, you cannot access JavaScript in PHP. So the constant you created...

```
define("SELECTitem", form.options.value);
echo SELECTitem; // returns "formoptionsvalue" (form concatenated with options and value)
```

What you should do is submit form.options.value and access it via $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
 define("SELECTitem", form.options.value);
```

What does "form.options.value" mean?
If i understand it right, it's your JS code.
But it doesn't work like that.

Also u can not access constant from other process.

You need to read some PHP books first.

Answer (score 0):

Title of question is good and generic: **Couldn't find constant error - PHP** but the body of it is very particular

For all of you who come here for the general answer please note that when you get here for **a not working class constant** then please check if you are using the fully qualified name of the class otherwise it will not work.

NOK: `constant('MyClass::MY_CONST');`

OK: `constant(MyClass::class . '::MY_CONST');`